# Asp.Net Core http requests shows Headers.ContentLength

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I am doing an http get call and I can see that `Headers.ContentLength` always returns null whereas I can see that in fiddler a value:
This is my code

```
string url = $"url";

HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => true;

HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler)
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(url)
};

httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Token {authToken.Value}");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

httpClientHandler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(string.Empty, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();


var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var length = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
```

ContentLength is always null. Fiddler below shows body length and also header length and Im downloading the data without any issue.

[image]

[image]

I need to be able to read content length header to decide if I will allow download. Why am I receiving null

Comment: Why is this tagged with `asp.net-core` (and `asp.net`) when you're only asking about using `HttpClient`?

Comment: Have you tried to call the [`TryComputeLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.trycomputelength?view=net-6.0) on the `response.Content`?

Comment: Found the issue. Once I commented ````httpClientHandler.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods```` it worked. What I suspect is that this call removes the header because it decompresses original payload (ContentLength is changed after decompression)

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint  in your `HttpResponseMessage response` to see what the status of the response looks like, and check which step is wrong, because your code as a whole is fine.

[image]